# How to set up a dead letter queue for each durableTopic?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have set up an application to listen to an ActiveMQ topic.  Here's the way I have configured it:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="jmsFactory"
    container-type="default" destination-type="durableTopic" client-id="CMY-LISTENER"
    acknowledge="transacted">
    <jms:listener destination="CMY.UPDATES"
        ref="continuingStudiesCourseUpdateListener" subscription="CMY-LISTENER" />
</jms:listener-container>


<bean id="jmsFactoryDelegate" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jmsFactory.brokerURL}" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="10" />
            <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="60000" />
            <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="60000" />
            <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
            <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How do I set up a dead letter queue for each topic for those messages to get copied into when they reach the maximum deliveries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature went into the most recent 5.5 release, you can find the info on the changes that were made [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3003):

There's a new boolean attribute 'destinationPerDurableSubscriber' on IndividualDeadLetterStrategy in you activemq.xml